# Add menu item to tabbed mvxtabsfragmentactivity xamarin android

Tags: android, menu, tabs, xamarin, menuitem

I have an activity that inherits `MvxTabsFragmentActivity`. I have 2 tabs, "ABC" and "DEF". I click them and they work correctly. I want to add "Navigation" items on top. (Menu one and Menu two) My other views inherited from `MvxActivity`. So I overrode `OnOptionsItemSelected` and had navigation. Now this class inherits MvxTabsFragmentActivity. I don't know how to add menu items.

This is what I want:
[image: take a look at what i want]

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. There is OnCreateOptionsMenu method in this too. (Its also an activity,so i just went one by one method and saw it there).
Also instead of OnOptionsItemSelected we have to use OnMenuItemSelected() method here and it works like a charm. Hope it helps others.